# WhereHas returning if the count is greater than 2

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query that checks against the users table and then accesses their credential. Although, I only want to return if credential count is `> 1`

The relationship is a `hasMany`

```
  $users = User::where('status', 1)
        ->whereHas('cred' function($q) {
            $q->where('Count('user_id') > 1')
          // $q->havingRaw('COUNT(user_id) > 1');
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `has` to check for count

```
$users = User::where('status', 1)->has('cred', '>', 1)->get();
```

[See Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)